# durandal messagebox close button on top

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application

by default [durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) messagebox box is like this : and named as : **messageBox.html**

```
<div class="messageBox">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 data-bind="html: title"></h3>z
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="message" data-bind="html: message"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">
        <button class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, html: $data, css: { 'btn-primary': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

now here, i would like to put X button on header right side :

```
<div class="modal-header">
            <h3 data-bind="html: title"></h3>
            <a>X</a>
        </div>
```

so i put the  X  in modal-header, but i am not able to figure out where and what code should write,so when user click on X , the popup will closed.

messageBox.js is like this :

```
define(function() {
    var MessageBox = function(message, title, options) {
        this.message = message;
        this.title = title || MessageBox.defaultTitle;
        this.options = options || MessageBox.defaultOptions;
    };

    MessageBox.prototype.selectOption = function (dialogResult) {
        this.modal.close(dialogResult);
    };

    MessageBox.defaultTitle = '';
    MessageBox.defaultOptions = ['Ok'];

    return MessageBox;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do knockout binding to the function closing modal

```
<div class="modal-header">
     <h3 data-bind="html: title"></h3>
     <span data-bind="click: function () { $parent.close(); }>X</span>
</div>
```

While Your JS file looks like:

```
define(function() {
    var MessageBox = function(message, title, options) {
        this.message = message;
        this.title = title || MessageBox.defaultTitle;
        this.options = options || MessageBox.defaultOptions;
    };

    MessageBox.prototype.selectOption = function (dialogResult) {
        this.modal.close(dialogResult);
    };

    MessageBox.prototype.close = function () {
        this.modal.close();
    };

    MessageBox.defaultTitle = '';
    MessageBox.defaultOptions = ['Ok'];

    return MessageBox;
});
```